# PHP PDO not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, pdo

i have declared a PDO and for some reason, the script stalls when declaring it.
It gives me no error, just stalls for some reason. I cant seem to get to the bottom of it. If i am doing something wrong, please let me know

```
<?php

 // this function creates a PDO that can be used to connect to our mysql server
 function getConnectionPDO($dbName){
     if(!empty($dbName)){
         $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname='.$dbName,'root','root');
         return $pdo;
     }
     else {
         return null;
     }
 }

 // gets login parameters
 function getLogin($username,$password){
     if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){
         $pass_hash1 = md5($password);
         $pass_hash2 = md5($pass_hash1); // hashes the password twice
         //creating connection
         $pdo = getConnectionPDO('User_Data');
         if($pdo != null){
             $query_string = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=:username AND password=:password';
             $prepare = $pdo->prepare($query_string); // preparing for query
             // binding parameters
             $prepare->bindParam(':username', $username);
             $prepare->bindParam(':password', $pass_hash2);
             // testing if query passed successfully
             $columns = $prepare->fetchColumn();
             if($columns == 1){
                 return true;
             }
             else {
                 return false;
             }
         }
         else {
             return false;
         }
     }
 }
?>
```

thanks in advance for the help =)

Comment: username field unique?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted doesn't seem to have a error, so it could be anything.

You might find it easier to debug if you pass the constructor its forth 'options' parameter with `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`.

This will make `PDO` throw an exception when it encounters an error.

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname='.$dbName,'root','root', array(
  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try:

```
 new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;port=8889;dbname=$dbName",'root','root');
```

Also add an

```
$prepare->execute();
```

after the last bindParam

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your connection is timing out. Can you verify that MySQL is running, and is running on port 8889?

If you're on Linux, run `netstat -tulpn`, find the `PID/Program Name` matching `XXXX/mysqld` and make sure the local address is `127.0.0.1:8889`, if it's not then your PDO has the wrong port configuration. If you're on Windows, you can run (in a command prompt with Administrator privilages `netstat -a -b` (You may need to press CTRL+C to stop the execution) and look for mysqld.exe, and make sure the local address is `0.0.0.0:8889`.